# Infinite slide plugin not working with a background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I am using infinite slide plugin(https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Infinite-Scroller-Plugin-jQuery.html). It's working perfectly with `img tag` but it's not working with a background image.

Please check the below code with background and without the background image.

I need to use with background image.

Would you help me out in this?

```js
 $(function(){$('.scroll1').infiniteslide();});
```

```css
   html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 .scroll1 {
  display: none;
 }
 .scroll1 img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 400px;
 }
 .banner_bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    min-height:100%;
}
.application_slider_1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg');
}
.application_slider_2{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-20.jpg');
}
.application_slider_3{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-10.jpg');
}
.application_slider_4{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpaper-pictures_KMw1jzE.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!--with background image-->
 <ul class="scroll1">
  <li><div class="application_slider_1 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_2 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_3 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_4 banner_bg"></div></li>
 </ul>

<!-- with img tag-->
<ul class="scroll1">
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-20.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-10.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpaper-pictures_KMw1jzE.jpg"></li>
 </ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-Scroller-Plugin-jQuery/infiniteslidev2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You div tag with bg - dont have size; Set fixed size;

```js
 $(function(){$('.scroll1').infiniteslide();});
```

```css
   html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 .scroll1 {
  display: none;
 }
 .scroll1 img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 400px;
 }
 .banner_bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    /*min-height:100%;*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.application_slider_1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg');
}
.application_slider_2{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-20.jpg');
}
.application_slider_3{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-10.jpg');
}
.application_slider_4{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpaper-pictures_KMw1jzE.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!--with background image-->
 <ul class="scroll1">
  <li><div class="application_slider_1 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_2 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_3 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_4 banner_bg"></div></li>
 </ul>

<!-- with img tag-->
<ul class="scroll1">
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-20.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpaper-10.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpaper-pictures_KMw1jzE.jpg"></li>
 </ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-Scroller-Plugin-jQuery/infiniteslidev2.js"></script>
```

Link
https://codepen.io/Hydrock/pen/KQaPoe

Comment: but how can I display the width:100% because I have to display full screen.

Comment: you must add size 100% to li container too. https://codepen.io/Hydrock/pen/rJWXrJ

Comment: But this plugin is not designed for full-screen images

Comment: Yes, In the codepen both answers are working for me. Please add codepen link in the answer. Thanks for the help and Upvote from my side